# Calculation of integrals transforming $N(μ,σ^2)$ to $N(0,1)$

Tags: normal-distribution, integral, transform

Let's say $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are known.

How can we calcuate the following integrals by transforming $X$ to $Z\sim N(0,1)$?

$$
\int_{c_1}^{c_2}(x-c)\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)dx \\
\int_{-\infty}^{c_1}(x-c)\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)dx
$$

where $c, c_1, c_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Use a change of variable to $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$.

Comment: Assuming you are allowed to use standard results like $\int_{-\infty}^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{z^2}{2}) dz = \Phi (a)$ you probably want to expand the first bracket after substituting $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. The term with a $z$ in the integrand is probably the hardest to deal with, but there is always integration by parts.

Comment: @BruceET I know with R. I want to solve this by hand. And I think there are not any undefined constants. Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry if my comment (now deleted) was unwelcome. I was under the impression you were asking for help.

Comment: You may find this easier if you separate the integrals  into $\int (x-\mu)\, f(x)\,dx - \int (c-\mu)\, f(x)\,dx$ especially if you consider the derivative of $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)$

Comment: @B.Liu thanks a lot for your help. Actually, for the term with $z$ , one needs to see that $\int_{a}^{b} z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(exp(-a^2/2)-exp(-b^2/2)\right)$.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis Glad to be of help - please consider self-answering the question! For some reason I tried to tackle the term with $z$ initially by integration by parts, and then realised a substitution is sufficient to get to what you stated.

Answer (score 1):

For both cases, we set $z=\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, and so $dz=\dfrac{dx}{\sigma}$ and $x=z\sigma+\mu$. Note that we change both $c_1$ and $c_2$ to $d_1$ and $d_2$, respectively, according to $z=\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. The same holds for $-\infty$.

Therefore, for the first case we get:

$$
\int_{d_1}^{d_2}(z\sigma+\mu-c)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)dz=
$$

$$
\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{d_1}^{d_2}z\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)dz
+
(\mu-c)\int_{d_1}^{d_2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)dz=
$$

$$
\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(exp(-d_1^2/2)-exp(-d_2^2/2)\right)
+
(\mu-c)\left(Φ(d_2)-Φ(d_1)\right).
$$

In a similar manner, for the second case we get:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{d_1}(z\sigma+\mu-c)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)dz=
$$

$$
\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{d_1}z\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)dz
+
(\mu-c)\int_{-\infty}^{d_1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)dz=
$$

$$
\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{d\to-\infty}\left(exp(-d^2/2)-exp(-d_1^2/2)\right)
+
(\mu-c)Φ(d_1)=
$$

$$
\dfrac{-\sigma exp(-d_1^2/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+(\mu-c)Φ(d_1).
$$

Great thanks to B.Liu for pointing out that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)dz=Φ(a).$$